# SignalR notification issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, signalr

I have a monitoring site which update data from the server to the clients. I'm using SignaR doing this . 
I have an issue , when I load the page I need to get the data the first time , then there is a worker on the server responsible for notifying the client each x time. 
I added a method to My Web API controller , so the page use it to get the current data , and I want to worker to use also to notify the clients. 
My problem , I don't want the first load page to make a notification (because I same the notification login in the same api method)
Is there a way to get the ConnectionID outside the Hub class.

Thanks in advance ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can reach out to the Hub outside the hub context:

```
var myHub = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
```